# combine multiple array values into one string value?

Tags: objective-c, arrays

I want to combine the array values into one string.
my arrays are like...

```
 array1=[@"fizan",@"nike",@"pogo"];
 array2=[@"round",@"rectangle",@"square"];
 array3=[@"frame",@"frame",@"frame"];
```

I need like this...

```
value1 = fizan round frame
value2 = nike rectangle frame
value3 = pogo square frame
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
NSArray *array1= @[@"fizan",@"nike",@"pogo"];
NSArray *array2= @[@"round",@"rectangle",@"square"];
NSArray *array3= @[@"frame",@"frame",@"frame"];
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:@[array1,array2,array3]];
NSMutableArray *output = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSString *a;
NSInteger count = array.count;

for (int i = 0; i<array1.count; i++) {
    a = @"";
    for (int j = 0; j<count; j++) {
        a = [a isEqualToString: @""] ? [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[array objectAtIndex:j] objectAtIndex:i]] : [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",a,[[array objectAtIndex:j] objectAtIndex:i]];
    }
    [output addObject:a];
}

for (int i = 0; i < output.count; i++) {
    NSLog(@"value %i -> %@",i+1,output[i]);
}
```

Hope this helps!

**UPDATE:**

```
NSArray *array1= @[@"fizan",@"",@"pogo"];
NSArray *array2= @[@"round",@"rectangle",@"square"];
NSArray *array3= @[@"frame",@"frame",@"frame"];

NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:@[array1,array2,array3]];
NSMutableArray *output = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSString *a;
NSInteger count = array.count;

for (int i = 0; i<array1.count; i++) {
    a = @"";
    for (int j = 0; j<count; j++) {
        a = [a isEqualToString: @""] ? [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[array objectAtIndex:j] objectAtIndex:i]] : [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",a,[[array objectAtIndex:j] objectAtIndex:i]];
    }
    [output addObject:a];
}

for (int i = 0; i < output.count; i++) {
    NSLog(@"value %i -> %@",i+1,output[i]);
}
```

I have tested this code. It works perfect. Check again and reconsider the issue.

Comment: if i have any of one array value is blank
like this
NSArray *array1= @[@"fizan",@"",@"pogo"];
NSArray *array2= @[@"round",@"rectangle",@"square"];
NSArray *array3= @[@"frame",@"frame",@"frame"];

then it gives error like
index 0 beyond bounds for empty NSArray

can you help me solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Do this

```
NSArray *array1 = @[@"fizan", @"nike", @"pogo"];
NSString *value = [array1 componentsJoinedByString:@" "];
NSLog(@"value = %@", value);
```

Output will get like

```
value = fizan nike pogo
```

For your case

```
    NSArray *completeArray = @[@[@"fizan",@"nike",@"pogo"], @[@"round",@"rectangle",@"square"], @[@"frame",@"frame",@"frame"]];

    NSMutableArray *resultArray = [NSMutableArray array];

    unsigned long count = 1;

    for (int i = 0; i< count; i++) {
        NSMutableArray *listArray = [NSMutableArray array];
        for (NSArray *itemArray in completeArray) {
            count = MAX(count,itemArray.count);
            if (i < itemArray.count) {
                [listArray addObject:itemArray[i]];
            }
        }
        [resultArray addObject:listArray];
    }

    for (NSArray *itemArray in resultArray) {
        NSString *value = [itemArray componentsJoinedByString:@" "];
        NSLog(@"value = %@", value);
    }
```

output

```
 value = fizan round frame
 value = nike rectangle frame
 value = pogo square frame
```

Comment: check the output in the question and your output

Comment: as you have edited the answer, it won't made any change;

Comment: your output is fizan nike pogo but the question suggests that it need fizan round frame